# CSS how to change a SVG on hover over link

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

As you can see, there is some css that needs to change the image when a user hovers over it.

```css
.dashboard-card-content:hover .right-arrow a {
  background-color: #29b1e9;
}

.dashboard-card-content:hover .right-arrow a svg path {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-container dashboard-card-content">
  <div class="gLoader-img">
    <img src="assets/images/comp-switch-logo2.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="gloaderSvg-wrapper"></div>
  <div class="dashboard-card-header-content">
    <h5>Policy Maintainance</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard-card-footer-content">
    <div class="right-arrow">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="assets/images/right-icon.svg" class="svg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The normal state is as desired.

[image]

The on hover state is not as desired. It is making the buttons background light blue as desired, but it does not make the arrow white.

[image]

This is the desired look on hover.

[image]

**Question**

How do I change the above htlm/scss to allow the image to turn white when a user hovers over it?

Comment: You should add code as a snippet and not just simply add it!

Comment: You need to embed the SVG code directly in your HTML (not `<img src="svg">`, but `<svg>…</svg>`), otherwise you have no “access” to any of its elements for formatting in the first place. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use object tag instead of img tag.
This is one of example.

```css
.svg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.svg:hover {
  filter: invert(27%) sepia(51%) saturate(2878%) hue-rotate(346deg) brightness(104%) contrast(97%);
}
```

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/icon-bike-black.svg" class="svg">
    Bike
  </object>
```

Answer (score 3):

i think there is no way to do that with `color` and you can use ways like this below

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.icon-arrow {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/icon-arrow-black.svg);
}
.icon-arrow:hover,
.icon-arrow:focus {
  filter: invert(27%) sepia(51%) saturate(2878%) hue-rotate(346deg) brightness(104%) contrast(97%);
}

body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  place-items: center center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <span class="icon icon-arrow"></span>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try playing with the `fill` css attribute. This will work on your arrows as I think they are shapes. This is the SVG counterpart to background-color. You might need to use classes or identifiers in the SVG to target only the arrows...

If that does not work, better show us the SVG so we can help a bit more.